# How can I return the data as multiple objects?

Tags: laravel, vuex

I set an empty array inside a state

```
const state = {
    jobs: []
}
```

Inside the component, I dispatch an action and the code looks like this:

```
created(){
    this.$store.dispatch('viewJobs');
}
```

The viewJobs actions looks like the following:

```
viewJobs: ({commit}) => {

    axios.get('/api/jobs')
        .then(res => {
            const jobss = res.data;

            console.log(jobss);

            commit('LIST_JOBS', jobss);

        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));   
}
```

And then the mutations looks like this:

```
'LIST_JOBS'(state, jobss){
    state.jobs.push(jobss);
}
```

From the laravel side, my controller looks like this:

```
    $jobs = Employment::all();

    return $jobs->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

When I load the page, am able to console log jobss, but the state does not get updated.

How can I successfully push the data to the state?

Comment: `{}, {}, {}` is not valid JSON. Please explain what you are trying achieve.

Comment: @levi I have edited my question for more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the entire array as a single element of `state.jobs`. Instead, you can use the Javascript spread operator, to push each element from the array:

```
state.jobs.push(...jobss)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `response()->json()`

```
return response()->json(Employment::all(),200);
```

and try use `{jobss:jobss}` in commit section

```
viewJobs: ({commit}) => {

    axios.get('/api/jobs')
        .then(res => {
            const jobss = res.data;

            console.log(jobss);

            commit('LIST_JOBS', {jobss:jobss});

        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));   
}
```

Another way, your vuex store looks like this

```
// state
export const state = () => ({
    items: []
})

// getters
export const getters = {
    items: state => state.items
}

// mutations
export const mutations = {
    SET_ITEMS (state, { items }) {
        state.items = items
    },
    PUSH_ITEM (state, { item }) {
        state.items.push(item)
    },
    UPDATE_ITEM (state, { index, item }) {
        state.items[index] = item
    },
    DELETE_ITEM: (state, index) => {
        state.items.splice(index.index, 1);
    }
}

// actions
export const actions = {
    setItems ({ commit }, { items }) {
        commit('SET_ITEMS', { items })
    },
    pushItem ({ commit,state }, { item }) {
        commit('PUSH_ITEM', { item })
    },
    deleteItem ({ commit,state }, { index }) {
        commit('DELETE_ITEM', { index })
    },

    updateItem ({ commit,state }, { index,item }) {
        commit('UPDATE_ITEM', { index,item })
    },
}
```

Then in your component call your action

```
 this.$axios.$get('/api/jobs')
        .then(res => {
            const jobss = res.data;

            console.log(jobss);

            this.$store.dispatch('your_store_name/setItems', {items:jobss});

        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: I looked at your answer once again a compared to what I read in the documentation for the actions. If we do need a mutation to change a state, why do we set state as an optional parameter inside the actions?

Comment: Sorry, I left the state variable because, in my example I also save the state values to cookie, like this `Cookies.set('cookie_name',state.items , { expires: 365 })`. If you want to access the state variable you need to define it like parameter

Comment: Understood. I was just more of wanting to understand the "when to use the state". So now I understand that in an action we can access a state. Appreciate the support